# WEBRtc for many cctv to one user

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, webrtc, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm building a react web application which can view live video feeds from my five webcams which point to different area of house. I want to use webRTC so that I don't have latency in my viewing.

I'm confused with webRTC broadcasting and receiving.

I am exploring AWS Kinesis video streams but it is complicated for me to test. Is there any services that I can use?

Thank You,

I have tried with some webRTC video conferencing application that found in online. But as for my application. I don't need that function.

Comment: To stream your cameras you would need them to have also a client application that then connects to your streaming device, just keep in mind this. Anyways It's unclear in the question whether you want to use webRTC or not